# Should I use Infura with Web3j for Event filter?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3j, filters, infura

I'm using Web3j with Infura for smart contract deployment, calling contract method and transactions. Now I want to use Filter contract event from log. Should I use Infura for this? Is Web3j filter works fine with Infura? Or I use a synced geth node to filter events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Infura with filters, according to the documentation.

> Note: filters are not supported on Infura.

https://docs.web3j.io/filters.html

Comment: do you know of any alternatives to Infura? I love how simple infura is to integrate with dApps, and I honestly wanted to **not** have to spin up my own client.