# How to get events on android with infura?

Tags: web3j, infura, android

I am developing an app on Android, but Web3j does not support events on infura ( [Should I use Infura with Web3j for Event filter?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32494/should-i-use-infura-with-web3j-for-event-filter) ) .

What are the options, I did not find any alternative library?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will work on Android, but try something like this:

```
WebSocketService webSocketService = new WebSocketService("wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/.....'", true);
webSocketService.connect(); 
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(webSocketService);
```

That worked for this generated method (with java 11):

```
public Flowable<TransferEventResponse> transferEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and keep you updated